# Many worlds: would branching occur in a universe with only two electrons in it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-interpretations

I understand Everett's fundamental insight: human beings and measurement devices are made up of the same quantum particles as the ones being measured, therefore it makes sense to postulate that we ourselves are in a superposition of observing two or more different outcomes while performing a quantum measurement.

But I'm not quite sure I understand in what circumstances branching occurs *when there are no humans and no measurements involved*.

Consider a simple universe that contains only two electrons $e_1$ and $e_2$. Suppose that they are initially separated by vast distances and do not interact. Then, they are made to intersect.

Is it correct to say that branching would never happen while the electrons are separated, but then branching would start immediately after the two electrons are brought close together?

In other words, would some of the fungible instances (as David Deutsch likes to call them) of $e_1$ get entangled with some of the fungible instances of $e_2$, branching the universal wave function? Or, because there is no particle decay and no change of spin, branching wouldn't occur, ever, in this hypothetical universe?

Comment: Could you tell us what a "fungible instance" is?

Comment: @flippiefanus The fungible instances of a particle are the set of all the copies of that particle from parallel universes. For example, in the double-slit experiment, the fungible instances of the photon are what cause the interference pattern to occur.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it correct to say that branching would never happen while the
> electrons are separated, but then branching would start immediately
> after the two electrons are brought close together?

Eh, depends on what you mean by branching. All the multiverse interpretation is, is that every superposition state is a universe. So even with just one electron that is in a superposition of states, this would imply that there are an infinite amount of "branches" if you were to "be" that electron. You don't really need the second electron to start talking about branches.

The second electron, if it interacts with the first, might create entangled states (Which are basically just superposition states of correlated outcomes of the two electrons). In that way now there are "branches" of all the different outcomes. One electron could be thought to be making a "measurement" on the other since their outcomes are correlated. So in some sense this could be a different definition of branching -- in which you are always asking what happens in enviornment (the second electron) in particular reference frame of some "observer" (the first electron).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

So if we confine the multiverse to only just an electron in a superposition, would that multiverse contain only two branches, ever?

I.e., one branch with the electron spinning up and another with the electron spinning down.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg, in the "electrons perspective" there is a 'branch' where it is spinning up and another where it is spinning down.

Comment: And those two branches are all there is in this toy universe?

Comment: at that moment as you've described it yes.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have two entangled electrons in the universe, then there is no environment to measure one (or both) of the electrons and make it entangled with the environment/mesure apparatus and breaking the entanglement with the other electron. So the system does not split into two separate wavefunctions at any time. The system will always remain entangled and in superposition.
Instead, if you had a measuring device, this could interact with one of the particle pairs, entangle itself with it, and disentangle the other electron from the first. The result will be a new "branching" for each measurement, each branch keeping the information on the measurement result from that branch, so we end up with branches in which the results of the same measurement of the experiment differ.